# How to use a variable from a shapefile coming from another different shapefile in field calculator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, field-calculator

I have two shapefile files "A" and "B" loaded in QGIS 3.22.

I would like to use a variable from one shapefile in the field calculator of another shapefile.

For file "A" I would like to use the variables `ident`, `x1`, `y1`, `end1x` and `end1y` to calculate a determinant (matrix) if the feature of "B" has the value of  `ident` equal to "A" (B=A), in this case I want to use `x2` and `y2` from "B" in field calculator within A.

attribute table A

[image]

attribute table B

[image]

field calculator try
[image]

expression

```
if ident@B=ident@B then

(x1*end1y*1)+(y1*1*x2)+(end1x*y2*1)-(x2*1*end1y)-(y2*1*x1)-(end1x*y1*1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This expression returns the attribute value from the `x2` field of layer B, where layer B's `ident` is equal to layer A's `ident`.

```
attribute(
    get_feature('B', 'ident', "ident"),
    'x2'
)
```

See the help pane in the field calculator for a more detailed explanation of the functions.

Note the use of single and double quotes - the second argument of `get_feature` is a field *name* and the third argument is a field *value*, in this case taken from layer A.

For readability of your final expression, you could set the layer B values to variables and call them with the `@` operator, like this:

```
with_variable('x2', attribute(get_feature('B', 'ident', "ident"), 'x2'),
with_variable('y2', attribute(get_feature('B', 'ident', "ident"), 'y2'),

(x1*end1y*1)+(y1*1*@x2)+(end1x*@y2*1)-(@x2*1*end1y)-(@y2*1*x1)-(end1x*y1*1)

))
```

Comment: this works great, thanks!!